# Redirect file type specific requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In my app, I have the srcs of many images like this:

path/other-path/my-image.jpg

This can get long and can expose some of my file structure to the outside world.

What can I do in .htaccess to redirect a given file extension to a directory?

i.e. my image src is simply "my-image.jpg", .htaccess sees that is a .jpg file and redirects to the folder "www.site.com/my-jpgs/" were "my-image.jpg" resides, thus loading the image.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/importers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/index.php

RewriteBase /

# Ignore rule if the real path exists, use that instead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Only use the filename and extension.
RewriteRule (.[^/]*)\.(gif|jpg|png) public_html/images$1.$2 [R,L]
```

---

I've sort of got it working, except the browser makes two requests that look like this:

Request URL:http://www.view.com/activity/enquiry/dropdown-btn.gif

Request URL:http://www.view.com/public_html/images/dropdown-btn.gif

The second being correct, how do I correct this so it doesn't make the first incorrect request?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of rewrite rules is very important in `.htaccess. Your problem is incorrect ordering of your rule. You need to move last rule to the top just below`RewriteEngine On`line to have external redirect before sending everything off to`index.php`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Ignore rule if the real path exists, use that instead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Only use the filename and extension.
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)*([^.]+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png))$ images/$1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/importers
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still requesting it twice.

Comment: What URL did you enter in your browser?

Comment: The url I am at is ht tp://www.site.com/activity/enquiry/50647
The GIF requests are in my edit.

Comment: Do you mean this gif request `Request URL:http://www.view.com/activity/enquiry/dropdown-btn.gif` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the incorrect request. That is basically sending the gif as a parameter for method enquiry of class activity, which is totally wrong.

Comment: Oh ok then I'm little confused. What is the original image URL sent to the server?

Comment: The image is simply: <img src="dropdown-btn.gif">

Comment: And this image is on a page with URL: `http://www.site.com/activity/enquiry/50647` ?

Comment: Ok I believe actual path of you image is `http://site.com/images/dropdown-btn.gif` I edited code based on that assumption. Check it now.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that it still doesn't work :(

Comment: You need to provide proper details like what is not working. `doesn't work` kind of sentence aren't going to help at all.